# Django models normalization

Tags: django, django-models, consistency

having a simple ordinary model like this

```
class Order(models.Model):
    open = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=8)
    high = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=8)
    low = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=8)
    close = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=8)
    time = models.DateTimeField()
    active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    complete = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

works for my case but as there's only up to 1 `active` order at the same time, keeping it consistent is a challenge. don't wanna use `transaction` so the idea of separating `active` attribute would be a solution. I wondered if there's any better idea? for example, adding `active` as a database related attribute or something like a hook (believe me when I say I don't know if that's an option)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [**`UniqueConstraint`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/constraints/#django.db.models.UniqueConstraint) to enforce that at most one `Order` has `active=True`:

```
from django.db.models import Q

class Order(models.Model):
    # …
    active = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(
                fields=('active',),
                condition=Q(active=True),
                name='at_most_one_active'
            )
        ]
```

Comment: It's a good one, thanks a lot. I don't wanna be a perfectionist, and sure it solves consistency situation but having `active` attribute for all the orders seems a bit redundant to me, don't you think so? I was thinking of saving `active` in another model but still doesn't seem likely to me

Answer (score 0):

what about checking this before save

```py
class Order(models.Model):
  ...
  

  def save(self,*args,**kwargs):
    if self.active: # then will check in the DB 
       objs = self.__class__.objects.filter(...).values_list(flat=True) # put your filters 
    if any(objs): # check if there is any True Value 
       raise MultiActiveOrdersError("Only On Order Can be Active")
    else :
      super().save(*args,*kwargs)
```

So you can Create the Object but to save it into the DB, it mustn't be any active ones else